# How does .NET 4.7.2 manage redirects for a dependency compiled in .NET Standard 2.0?

Tags: .net, nuget, dependency-management, .net-standard-2.0

**Background**

I have a large, old, monolithic application that currently targets .NET Framework 4.7.2 and uses several recently-written modules (also targeting `net472`) with no issues. There is also a recently-written module that targets .NET Standard 2.0, and it's giving me some problems.

All modules are loaded into the main application using Nuget packages.

**The Issue**

When attempting to call the principal method of the module (i.e., at runtime, in the deployed application), it errors out saying that it failed to find a particular version of `System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource`, despite that DLL existing in the appropriate `\bin` folder.

The dependency on `System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource` comes from `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`, which has dependencies on it via both `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` and `System.Data.SqlClient`.

I had suspected that the fact that an *EntityFrameworkCore* package is being called from a `net472` application would have something to do with it (and it still may), but **the existing `net472` modules also use the Core package without errors.** The exact same version, even!

**Complicating Factors**

- The new module is only a class library, while the old modules are full-fledged WPF applications.
- I can't upload new Nuget packages to our server, so with each change I make, I have to copy the DLLs from the module's `\bin\Debug` folder into the `\bin` folder at the application's install directory.

**What Hasn't Worked**

- Installing the `System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource` Nuget package into the module. I have tried 4.0.3.0 (what the error message claims to be looking for), 4.5.0 (what the other modules expect), and 4.5.1 (what I think corresponds to the file version already in the install directory, see below).
- Creating a `net472` project in the module's solution to consume the `netstandard2.0` project without Nuget, then redirecting the main app to use that project via a DLL reference.

**What Has Worked**

- Creating a new folder in the install folder's `\bin` directory to contain only the new module's desired version of `System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll`, namely file version `4.6.26515.6`. The `\bin` folder already contains version `4.6.26919.2`, but the module doesn't like that one.

This is a kludge, though. I shouldn't have to package two versions of the same DLL just because I have a Nuget package built on .NET Standard......should I?

Where do I go from here?

**Additional Information**

Here's the relevant fuslogvw entry. Note that it claims to be looking for version 4.0.3.0, despite `MyApp.exe.config` having a redirect specifying `0.0.0.0-4.5.1`, and despite VS showing `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`'s dependency as `System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource (4.5.0)`.

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (10/28/2019 @ 1:22:30 PM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80131040. No description available.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\myApp\install\MyApp.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
(Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/myApp/install/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = MyApp.exe
Calling assembly : Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\myApp\install\MyApp.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Redirect found in application configuration file: 4.0.3.0 redirected to 4.5.1.0.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/myApp/install/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/myApp/install/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/myApp/install/bin/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.DLL.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\myApp\install\bin\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll
LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase.
LOG: Assembly Name is: System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.3.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Minor Version
ERR: The assembly reference did not match the assembly definition found.
ERR: Run-from-source setup phase failed with hr = 0x80131040.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

Here is the entry from `MyApp.exe.config`:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.5.1" newVersion="4.5.1" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Very unclear how a "separate folder" solved this problem.  Be sure to include the Fuslogvw.exe trace in your question, do expect to need a bindingRedirect in the app.config file.

Comment: The folder thing was so I could have the version of the DLL that I know works for the new module as well as the one that I know works for the others. Adding the new folder to the `.exe.config` file like `<probing privatePath="bin\myModule;bin;"/>` made it look there first. Hypothetically, if the other modules were to fail with the `myModule` version, the one in the `\bin` folder could then be loaded.

Comment: Good God, the answer was staring me in the face the whole time!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the answer is "like any other redirects."

The fuslogvw dump showed the exact problem, and explains all the other errors I've been seeing. The DLL that I wanted to consolidate to (the one being used by all other modules, i.e., file version 4.6.26919.2) is *not* assembly version 4.5.1, but **4.0.3.1**.

Correcting the binding redirect in `myApp.exe.config` resolved the problem.